# mysql partial word searching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to search like the below query but it is not working in MySQL

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (title,description) 
 AGAINST ('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I want below output

> testproduct, producttest

Can anybody help me on this..?

Answer (score 36):

currently, only support prefix, not support suffix:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (title,description) 
 AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

By the way, MySQL full text search will be bottleneck when the website request is large, and it is vulnerable and unstable for some special search word, thus often lead to slow query and database crash. Use Elastic Search as soon as possible.

Comment: How about if exp in AGAINST is not single word but phrase (some word or parts of words)?

Comment: it is true when handling huge number of search requests such as e-commerce web application, one should really look into ElasticSearch or Redis for better performance search

Answer (score -6):

Use LOCATE instead... or better yet, use Lucene and forget MySQL for searches.

Comment: What's wrong with MySQL for searching? I find it very very good and I work with hundreds of millions of records. I have a feeling most people do not know much about MySQL and thus the problems.