# How to search inside a table

Tags: mysql

[How to search inside a SQL table for a phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864407/how-to-search-inside-a-sql-table-for-a-phrase)

Related to my previous question. I use this query to search inside a database

```
SELECT *
       FROM clients
       WHERE MATCH(search_text) 
       AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) LIMIT 5
```

The problem is it matches words like this:

Search Term: `foo`

Entry:

- foo1 (no match)
- foo 1 (match)
- foo bar (match)
- barfoobar (no match)

How can I make it so that it matches all of the entry examples I have given

Comment: have you tried search term: %foo%   ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Look at this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682506/mysql-partial-word-searching If you search for foo* you can get foo1, but don't seem to be possible to get barfoobar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` statement

```
SELECT *
   FROM clients
   WHERE search_text LIKE '%foo%'
```

For your question, use single quotes ''

```
SELECT *
   FROM clients
   WHERE MATCH(search_text) 
   AGAINST('?')
```

Ref: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx

Comment: I want to keep searching in natural mode, I need the existing query modified